# What's a good simple python web-server

Tags: web-development

I want to do some web-development with Python 3.3 on a Windows box. I have no interest in frameworks; is there a good, simple, easy-to-get-started-with web server I can use for this? (I.e. similar to Easy-PHP or Apache or similar). With no/minimal config.

It must have auto-restart (as in, if a pythong file is changed, the server should use the new version rather than a cached version).

I've found http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2012/12/08/setting-up-a-rock-solid-python-development-web-server/ - which is good except it's centred around frameworks. I want something that stands alone. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you like Apache, you can use [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), which is an Apache HTTP Server module that provides a WSGI compliant interface for hosting Python 2.3+ based web applications.

- works on [Windows](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows) ([binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi))
- supports Python Python 3.1 or later. (for Python 2.X you need at least Python 2.3)
- provides [automatic reloading of source code when an application is changed](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode)

Comment: Thanks. This does potentially do what I want and is an excellent, informative answer, however it fails the "simple" test. The "Quick" configuration page for example looks like: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide - and assumes more knowledge than I have. So I'm not sure I'll be able to use it. Are there no actually simple ones?

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan [`wsgiref.simple_server`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#examples)? Doesn't get more simple than that, and it's included in the standard library. If you want a *decent* web server that is fit for production use, you'll have to do some configuration. For any language.